# Django Forms - JQuery datetime picker doesn't show when field has initial data

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates, datetimepicker

I have a form with 2 datetime fields, I'm using jquery ui 1.10.1, jquery 1.8.3 and [datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

I have no problems using datetime picker on clean form, but can't get it to show for instantiated form.

Things I tried:

Instantiating datetimepicker same way as for clean form: 
http://jsfiddle.net/neara/epHa4/.
Shows error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<s> has no method 'log'`

Instantiating datetimepicker with `'setDate'`: 
http://jsfiddle.net/neara/epHa4/1/
Doesn't do anything, no errors, no datetime picker.

How to make the datetime picker to work?

**HoW I Made It Work**

```
$('#start_datetime').datetimepicker({
                timeFormat: 'H:m:s',
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$('#end_datetime').datetimepicker({
                timeFormat: 'H:m:s',
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

Supplying the correct format for time and date of the value attr in input field, made it all work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jf8Cs/

I think this code may work..

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id='start_datetime' value="2013-04-07 16:10:00"/>
    <input type="text" id='end_datetime' value="2013-04-07 18:10:00"/>
</form>

$('#start_datetime').datetimepicker({
                showSecond: true,
                timeFormat: 'H:m:ss',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
$('#end_datetime').datetimepicker({
                showSecond: true,
                timeFormat: 'H:m:ss',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```